# SQL JOIN vs LIKE (where data is stored in row vs another table)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I've done some research and have not been able to find a definitive answer.

**What is better, in terms of performance.**

*NOTE: There are only 10 possible tags with a max length of 160 char (if all were chosen).*

---

**ONE table** with 3 columns: id, stuff, tags ...
where the tags column would be a varchar

and query it like so: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE %tagname%`

### OR

**TWO tables:**

- tableA columns = id, stuff
- tableB columns = id, tag

and query it like so: `SELECT * FROM tableA A INNER JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.tag = 'tagname'`

---

Illustration --

Row in tableA would look like: 123 | some data

Row in tableB would look like: 123 | tagname

**I'm simply asking** is it better to store tags WITHIN a row or in a separate table in terms of performance if there are not alot of tags.

Comment: I don't understand why you are comparing join vs like...
Why in the 2nd query you have _= 'something'_ ?

Comment: Perhaps you are saying that id in tableB are not unique and can have multi tag?

Comment: Can you illustrate it with 2row in first case and 2 row in tableA and tableB ?

Comment: Ever heard of [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)? From the point of normalization your first solution is just plain ugly! From the point of performance: You have to try that for yourself and see which one is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is better, in terms of performance.

Donald Knuth is credited with having said "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil.*"  It is understood that, by that, he was expressing that one should not normally build things for **performance** but rather for **correctness** and only then conduct optimisations to bring the application within the performance requirements.

What *are* your performance requirements?  Some people might want to minimise memory utilisation; others may want to minimise CPU time; others still might mean something entirely different by "performance".

Even if one assumes that you meant "which operation will be fastest", the answer will generally depend on various factors including disk technology, storage engine, index design, table size...

So, what should you do? **Normalise until it hurts; denormalise until it works.**

Your first approach violates [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  Don't do it unless you have some overriding reason (which you hardly ever will).

Answer (score 2):

Definitely the second option is better.

You can define indexes so it will work faster thatn full scan, you can combine conditions `tag1 and (tag2 or tag3)`, you can get some aggregated data from tags? you can group by tags? find similar instances with similar groups of tags.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the second option.

The first approach mandates a full table scan (which amounts to checking every single record of the table), whereas the result set in the second approach can be built exploiting indexes (assuming indexes are defined over the primary keys [which they usually are automatically] and the `tag` column).

the actual performance benefit depends on the optimizer of your db engine. there should be some command or utility that produces the 'explain plan', a summary of the way the query will be processed.

the contents might be double dutch to you but your db admin should know how to generate and how to read it.